# Trouble with CGI and table looping

Tags: html, perl, loops, cgi

I'm trying to create a table using cgi, populating it with content from an array, but I can't seem to find any answers online that solve my issue. I only have experience in languages like Java, and C++, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing when it comes to scripting, but here's what I have.

```
$c -> start_html(-title=>'Hello World'),

$c -> start_table({ -border => 1, -width => %50},
    while($i <= 4){
            $c -> tr({
                while($j <= 7 && $i + $j <=26){
                    $c -> td($alpha[$i + $j]),
                    $j++,
                }}),
            $i++,
    },
$c -> end_table,

$c -> end_html;
```

In my mind this seems like it would work, but it keeps returning a compilation error at  while($i <=4), and says nothing else about the error. I could really use some help understanding this.

Comment: The syntax error is that you're trying to stick a `while` loop in the middle of a function call. [That's not going to work](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html).

Comment: The error message really should say a bit more.

Comment: That would not work in Java or C++ either.

Comment: okay, I more or less get why it doesn't work, but what can I do to get the same effect?

Comment: Please consider that CGI has been removed from the Perl core and that the HTML generation functionality is deprecated within CGI.

Comment: Turn on `use strict;` `use warnings;`. This makes perl a lot fussier about what's allowed, and removes a lot of the more unusual behaviours.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used): HTML Generation functions should no longer be used. (The documentation also includes some alternatives)

Answer (score 1):

To get the same effect as what you're trying to do, you could use the "map" function with a range and you'd end up with something like this.

```
my $i=0;
$c->table({-border=>1, -width => "%50"},
    map { $c->Tr(
        map { $c->td(($i<=26 ? $alpha[$i++] : ""),
            ); } (0..7)
        ) } (0..4)
    );
```